# Sass at Multiple Physical Locations

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am about to start a new Sass project where the work will need to be carried out from multiple physical locations on different machines including laptops.

The 1st location is a standard setup with compass etc all running ok.
The second again has compass setup but cannot be networked as such to the first.
The third would be laptops etc.

So the question:

What is the best way to work access the same sass file from all 3 locations ( different times) without carrying a stick or drive around ?

Google drive ?
ftp down load at each?

Also concerned that someone may not get on to the latest version before modifying it.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/ on a server

Answer (score 0):

When any sort of code is going to be worked on in multiple locations, it's always best to use some sort of version control system.  Ideally, any time any code is being done, it should use a version control system, but I'll overlook that.

A version control system (VCS) will allow you to make changes in one place, store them in a central place, and then get those changes on other machines.  It will also mean you can check what changes were made when, and find what caused something to break a little easier.

There's a multitude of different options out there, and it comes down to whether or not you want to host your own server, use a generally available one, pay a small amount each month to keep servers private etc.

The obvious candidate (being the seemingly current favourite) would be to use git, where you can have your own server or use something like github.  But there's also oter options including (but not limited to):

- CVS
- SVN
- Mercurial

Which option you go for will depend on your preference really.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one working on the code and don't care much about safety, which versioning systems provide, you can very easily put your project on a Dropbox and set desktop application to sync only selected directories, ignoring others.

I use this method even though I use Git, just because sometimes I just want to not commit changes and continue working on them in different location. I fire up other computer and I am right where I left everything (including text editor settings, plugins, etc.)